# What's this N symbol?

Tags: user-interface

What's this N symbol? It shows up in various menus sometimes. And how do I get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that something has a notification for you, usually (but not always) an update. To get rid of it, tap the control with the 'N' badge, then follow the 'N's down until you reach the screen with the actual notification.